# jquery jscrollpane: scrollbars disappear on partial postback

Tags: jquery, postback, jscrollpane, partial

I am using jquery jscrollpane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) on my webpage. I have couple of partial postbacks on the page (on other controls) kicked off by a timer_tick. The scrollbars appear perfectly well on Page_load, but disappears on partial postback. I presume it could be a generic jquery issue than a jscrollpane thing.

Thanks for your help.

Devang.

Comment: Can you include any sample code or a link to your website that is having the issue?

Comment: My scrollbar disappears too, not after postback, but after applying `.scrollTo` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reinitialise the scrollpanes after loading content. Additionally, if you are loading content into the element you have applied jScrollPane to then you will need to use the getContentPane() api method to get a reference to the element you need to load the content into (as jScrollPane will have changed the markup of your page slightly):

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html

Comment: simply re-initialising the scrollpanes dint work for me, then i placed the div (which was the target scrollpane) outside the update panel and it worked. But I think what you saying is right too, I somehow overlooked getContentPane() method. It would have saved me a lot of time :).